# Reading Position Indicator based on DIV instead of the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, progress

I want to show a Reading Position Indicator on my site.
Unfortunately, the site is much longer than the text to read.
The content is inside a single DIV called "content-wrapper".

At the moment I'm using the HTML5 progress element (https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-progress-element.html) and added it to my site like in this example: https://css-tricks.com/reading-position-indicator/

It's working fine so far. The problem is, that the progress is calculated based on the lenght of the whole page. Is there any way to limit the progress on a single DIV?

This is my JS code:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {  
  var winHeight = $(window).height(), 
      docHeight = $(document).height(),
      progressBar = $('progress'),
      max, value;

  /* Set the max scrollable area */
  max = docHeight - winHeight;
  progressBar.attr('max', max);

  $(document).on('scroll', function(){
     value = $(window).scrollTop();
     progressBar.attr('value', value);
  });
});
```

Comment: as far i understood, are you wanting this. ` var winHeight = $('#div').height(), 
      docHeight = $('document').height(),`

Comment: great, change it to an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: If this answer fixes your problem then you can also Accept the answer.

Comment: I had to wait a few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using height of whole window.
You should use "your div's height".
like:

```
var winHeight = $('#div').height(), docHeight = $('document').height(),
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to set your:

```js
var docHeight = &('#content-wrapper').height();
```