# Reading progress bar for each article in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change my progress bar for the whole page to each article in one page. Tried code from([Reading Position Indicator based on DIV instead of the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399449/reading-position-indicator-based-on-div-instead-of-the-whole-page)), but it works only with the first div.

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  var winHeight = $(window).height(),
    docHeight = $(document).height(),
    progressBar = $('progress'),
    max, value;

  /* Set the max scrollable area */
  max = docHeight - winHeight;
  progressBar.attr('max', max);

  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    value = $(window).scrollTop();
    progressBar.attr('value', value);
  });
});
```

```css
progress {
  /* Positioning */
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* Get rid of the default border in Firefox/Opera. */
  border: none;
  /* Progress bar container for Firefox/IE10+ */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* Progress bar value for IE10+ */
  color: #E60000;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: transparent;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #E60000;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #E60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress value="0"></progress>
```

Comment: You need to post an example of your article html too.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand you need to change multipe progress bars.
Hope this will help you:

```
$('progress').each(function(index,elem) {
    elem.attr('value', value);
});
```

Do it the same for `'min'` and `'max'`.